# Capturing with parentheses - what went wrong?

Tags: regex

> 415-555-1234
>   650-555-2345
>   (416)555-3456
>   202 555 4567
>   4035555678
>   1 416 555 9292

For my regex lessons, I'm trying to capture the area code of the above numbers.
Now I've got the expression below which matches all the numbers, but my first pair of parentheses is not capturing anything.

```
1?\s?\\(?(\d{3})\s?-?\\)?(\d{3})\s?-?(\d{4})
```

Have I somehow converted them into a non-capturing group? How to fix?

RegexOne.com just ran off and left me alone on this one.

Comment: Which regex system are you using (which host language)?

Comment: use [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) instead

Comment: regex101 says my expression is invalid, which means I'll be busy for a while. Thanks! Will check it out.

Comment: That link shows all groups captured correctly: all area codes are captured as group 1.

Comment: Yeh I got it working there too. I guess RegexOne was just acting crazy. Thanks.

Comment: @dwilbank: This is a bit of a bump, but if you're wondering why regex101 said your expression was invalid and why it did not work on regexone, it's because you double escaped backslashes. So instead of `\(` you were doing `\\(`. If you're looking to learn, check out http://regex101.com/quiz/

Answer (score 0):

Use `[(]` and `[)]` to avoid the backslashes and possible double backslashes (because of escaping) and check if this fixes your problem.

Otherwise your regexp looks OK, `(\d{3})` should match and capture the first 3 digits.

In the question, please indicate which host programming language you are using. There may be backslash escaping issues related to the language. The general rule of thumb is to either use a single backslash (`\(` and `\d` in e.g. Perl, Ruby, JavaScript) or a double backslash (`\\(` and `\\d` in e.g. Java and C++) consistently in your regexp.

Comment: Thanks. I did the square brackets but they didn't work. Not sure what flavor of regex RegexOne website uses. regex101 is showing me some errors in my expression and I'll see what it says...

Answer (score 0):

This regex worked on http://regexone.com/example/1

```
1?\s?\(?(\d{3})\s?-?\)?\d{3}\s?-?\d{4}
```

What I did to fix it.

1. Remove the double slash when you escaped the parentheses.
2. Remove the second and third capture groups. (This seemed to confuse the test code)